# "To halt" the strike

Tags: grammar

> The workers are not going **to halt** the strike without proper delineation and acceptance of their demand.

What are the other words so we can use in place of "*to  halt*" - - Suppose they are not in a mood to stop the strike until the fulfillment of their demands.

Comment: What effect / feeling / etc are you trying to elicit with the alternate word?

Comment: Suppose they are not in a mood to stop strike until the fulfilment of their demand

Comment: I think the most commonly used term in Britain would be *call-off the strike*.

Comment: I edited the question body and added some formatting. I also want to edit the title and apply proper tags but I am not too sure. Are you looking for single words or  alternate phrases? Can you add your research please?

Answer (score 3):

I would certainly NOT USE ***break*** unless it meant aggressive action from the employers, the government, or other outside forces.

If it is the result of a strike ballot, or the actions of strikers themselves, the term most commonly used in Britain is ***call off the strike***; or ***call an end to the strike***. –

Comment: @DavidGarner Apologies. Clearly you are right. I will amend.

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of potentially volatile context it is always preferable to use *positive* language.  Don't look for a 'better' negative, turn it into a positive:

> The striking workers will return to work when their demands have been delineated and accepted.

This answer deals with the 'to halt' issue only.  What 'delineate' might mean here is another matter.

Comment: Hi @clark - We don't like all caps here, so I've edited some better formatting into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about [***lift** the strike*](https://www.google.fr/search?q=busser%27s+station&biw=385&bih=253&prmd=mniv&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic26iYwe_KAhWFuBoKHSXCBUgQ_AUIBCgA#q=%22lifted+the+strike%22)?

> lift: to stop or put an end to (a boycott, blockade, etc.) [Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lift)
>
> *The workers are not going to **lift** the strike without proper delineation and acceptance of their demand.*

Answer (score 0):

'stop',break','terminate'-all these words can be used in place of 'halt' which itself is a perfectly acceptable word in the context.

Answer (score 0):

The word **strike** usually collocates with "**end**" / "**call off**" in the sense you are looking for

Call off: to decide to stop something that is already happening.
Eg:

```
... journalists have called off a 24-hour strike after receiving a new pension offer from management ...
```